# SSH RDP Tunnel and Port Connection

Tags: ssh, port, rdp, connection

Tried doing some research but can't really figure out the solution (or how to troubleshoot further) for this problem.

Objective and Reasoning for setting this up:
SSH Tunnel RDP from work to home computer. At work, most ports are blocked, but I am able to use SSH.

Set-Up:
Macbook Pro (at Work) --> Internet --> HomeModem --> SSHserver and Windows 10 Pro

I am able to connect directly to Windows 10 (from a friends house or local lan) without any issues. When I connect from WAN (not at work) I have port forwarding on my router at home setup for 338900 --> 3389 Windows 10 and 22 --> 22 SSHserver

I am able to connect to my SSHserver (Debian 8) from work and everywhere without any issues.

Attempts:
From my mac I have tried:

ssh -p 22 -L 3400:192.168.1.2:3389 root@WANIP | RDP: 192.168.1.2:3400 = no connection

ssh -p 22 -L 3400:192.168.1.2:338900 root@WANIP | RDP: 192.168.1.2:3400 = no connection

ssh -p 22 -L 3400:WANIP:338900 root@WANIP | RDP: WANIP:3400 = no connection

All these attempts have been made from a WAN connection where I can just connect using: RDP WANIP:338900 = connection

Any direction and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? You need to connect from work to win10 via rdp?

Comment: yes, I need to connect from work to home Win10 RDP but at work most ports are blocked so I wanted to try and set-up ssh tunnel for it as direct RDP connection does not work.

Comment: Can you connect from debian (ssh server) to win10? telnet 192.168.1.2 3389

Comment: telnet: could not resolve 192.168.1.2:3389/telnet: Name or service not known

Comment: between address and port must be space and not a colon

Comment: Trying 192.168.1.2...
Connected to 192.168.1.2.

Comment: It's obvious that the people that manage your work network don't allow those connections, so why are you trying to circumvent them? If you have a legitimate business reason to do this then take it to them and ask them to make an exception for you.

Comment: RDP is allowed on the company wired network. Issue is when I take my MacbookPro to work and have to connect to the company wifi which is public only and thus the restrictions. Ethernet connection is inconvenient for small and quick tasks. Thus this need. Please be helpful instead of trying to explain my company policy to me. Thanks.

Comment: `Ethernet connection is inconvenient for small and quick tasks` - So you do have a solution but don't want to use it because you feel that it's inconvenient. That makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh -p 22 -L 3400:192.168.1.2:3389 root@WANIP
```

it's a correct command. I just checked in my environment. I have used the following command to create ssh tunnel

```
# ssh -L 192.168.1.6:3389:192.168.88.176:3389 alex@WAN.IP -p 2222
# netstat -an | grep 3389
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.6:3389            0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

After that I'm able to connect to 192.168.1.6:3389 via RDP.

On Debian you should check file /etc/ssh/sshd_config. There could be some restrictions

```
Match User alex
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

On your mac you should check /etc/ssh/ssh_config for the same restrictions.

Comment: both ssh configs have x11 forwarding and allow tcp forwarding set to yes. not sure why but mine will still not connect. thank you for your help though!

Comment: got it. connected after using localhost:port instead of previously listed ip:port

Comment: Strange. Should work. I can only advise to run ssh -v (with debug option) and check the output. Perhaps there would be the answer.